# Global data between activities

Tags: android

I have a activity that shows a list of products and a detail view where I can edit these products. I want to access the same list of products from both activities.

How do I store/use this global data between these multiple activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern: create a class and limit it to have only one instance that will hold a list of products. After that, access this instance and the same list from both of your activities:

```
    // singleton Manager
public class ProductManager {
    private static ProductManager sInstance;
    private List<Product> mProducts;

    // private constructor to limit new instance creation
    private ProductManager() {
        // may be empty
    }

    public static ProductManager getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new ProductManager();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return new ArrayList<>(mProducts);
    }

    // add logic to fill the Products list
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        mProducts = new ArrayList<>(products);
    }
}
```

Access it later from both activities:

MyListActivity.java:

```
// set products once you get them
ProductManager.getInstance().setProducts(yourProductsList);
// ...
```

DetailsActivity.java:

```
// get the same list 
ProductManager.getInstance().getProducts();
// ...
```

Comment: static variables are shared between class instances so there is no need for a singleton

Comment: This probably is an overkill for only two activities, but the design is better in my opinion. This list will be accessible from anywhere in the app and may encapsulate all the logic, caching and other stuff.

Comment: *but the design is better in my opinion* what are you comparing it to?

Comment: Better than using inheritance and a static variable in a parent activity

Comment: Sure, but nobody mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

1) You can define array List as a static in Application Level or Base Activity.

2) Pass array List to other Activity using serializable or parcelable.

3) You have more data in array list then you can use SharedPreferences.