# Pass Objects between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm devlopping an Android app made of multiple Activities and I have to pass ab Object between them, but I can't pass it by using intents because the class of the object doesn't implement serializable, how can I do it?
I CAN'T MODIFY THE SOURCE CODE OF MY CLASS
Thanks :)

```
public class MyClass { //stuff }
//I can't modify this source code
MyClass m = new MyClass(); //object I have to pass
```

Comment: What exactly is this object? What is its Java class?

Comment: It' a MongoDBAndroidDriver class

Comment: My guess is that it should be a singleton, either directly or through some sort of wrapper. So, you are not passing it around, but everything can refer to it. Regardless, you have no means of passing it between activities, so it is either going to be a singleton or you are going to have to stick to a single activity (e.g., using multiple fragments).

Comment: @GCM4IB You must not pass this kind of classes through Intent it will error prone.

Comment: What can I do? I've thought that I can rewrite my app using fragment, but it'll take too much time

Comment: @GCM4IB Just write singleton class as per Commonsware .

Comment: Can I use Gson to encode my class to a String, pass it through intents and then decode it?

Comment: What's a singleton class?

Comment: @GCM4IB Share your code for initializing MongoDBAndroidDriver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37385493/908821 @GCM4IB, here's an example of the singleton solution

Comment: This has been asked time and again: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+object+between+activities. Please do a search before creating new questions. Also, as mentioned by others, what you are trying to accomplish here is not a good idea. You should only pass simple data -- if anything -- between intents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose there is a data object class named StudentDataObject having some data types.

```
StudentDataObject studentDataObject = new StudentDataObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String studentDataObjectAsAString = gson.toJson(studentDataObject);
```

Now we are passing it from one activity to another activity using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MyStudentObjectAsString", studentDataObjectAsAString);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now we are in new activity, we get that object here using following line.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String studentDataObjectAsAString = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyStudentObjectAsString");
StudentDataObject studentDataObject = gson.fromJson(studentDataObjectAsAString, StudentDataObject.class);
```

Activity itself know where from I am called, so we can directly write **getIntent()** method.

Here we only need to add one dependency of **GSON**  we can add it using following line in **build.gradle** file.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

And one thing is that implement **StudentDataObject** as a **Parcelable** and if showing error then just press **alt+Enter** and implement methods.
Try this once, Hope it will work.

Sample Example for StudentDataObject should be like :-

```
  public class StudentDataObject implements Parcelable {
         // fields
        //empty constructor
        //parameterised constructor
        //getters and setters
       //toString method
        //last implement some Parcelable methods 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was about to do

Comment: @GCM Welcome, If you have doubts in above sample then let me know

Answer (score 2):

First of all create Parcelable data model.

```
public class DataModel implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<DataModel> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<DataModel>() {
     public DataModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new DataModel(in);
     }

     public DataModel[] newArray(int size) {
         return new DataModel[size];
     }
 };

 private DataModel(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }
```

}

put object into intent

```
intent.putExtra("KEY", object);
```

get object from intent

```
object = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("KEY");
```

Comment: DataModel is the class of the Object I have to pass?

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you:

```
public class EN implements Serializable {
//... you don't need implement any methods when you implements Serializable
}
```

FirstActivity

```
EN enumb = new EN();
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("en", enumb); //second param is Serializable
startActivity(intent);
```

SecandActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
en = (EN)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("en"); //Obtaining data 
}
```

[Passing data through intent using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable)

Comment: My class can't implement serializable, it's a compiled class, I can't modify the source code

Comment: implements Serializable in your class

Comment: //... you don't need implement any methods when you implements Serializable

Comment: What does it mean? In your class code you implements serializable, am I wrong?

Comment: if u want to pass an object from one activity to another activity so it implements Serializable or Parcelable interface

Answer (score 1):

Here is my object class *Book.java*

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class Book implements Parcelable {
  // book basics
  private String title;
  private String author;

  // main constructor
  public Book(String title, String author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
  }

  // getters
  public String getTitle() { return title; }
  public String getAuthor() { return author; }

  // write object values to parcel for storage
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(author);
  }

  public Book(Parcel parcel) {
    title = parcel.readString();
    author = parcel.readString();
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Book>() {

    @Override
    public Book createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
      return new Book(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public Book[] newArray(int size) {
      return new Book[0];
    }
  };

  public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
  }
}
```

Now you can pass object like this

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Book book = new Book(mBkTitle.getText().toString(),
                mBkAuthor.getText().toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Book", book);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```

Now object will be received like this in receiving *ReceivingActivity.java*

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Book book = intent.getParcelableExtra("Book");

    mBkTitle.setText("Title:" + book.getTitle());
    mBkAuthor.setText("Author:" + book.getAuthor());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement parcelable and then pass it via intent. Dont use Serializable cause is way slower than parcelable.

Read here how to make your object parcelable: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

after you dont it, pass your object like this:

```
intent.putExtra("KEY", your_object);
```

to read it:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("KEY");
```

Comment: I can't modify the source code of my class, so I can't implement Parcelable

Comment: If you can't do that, then it's not possible. If you want you can make a new parcelable object, like a clone of your existing one by setting the values from the old object to the new one, or you can pass only the important parts like id, name, description etc..

Answer (score 0):

Extend the class and implement serializable or parcelable in the inherited class and use its objects as in other answers.

```
Class NewClass extends MyClass implements serializable  {
//Create a constructor matching super
}
```

Use objects of this class instead of my class

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom object from one activity to another through intent in 2 ways.

1. By implements **Serializable**
2. By implements **Parcelable**

(1) By implements **Serializable** no need to do anything just implement **Serializable**
into your class like

```
public class Note implements Serializable {
  private int id;
  private String title;
}
```

(2) By implementing **Parcelable** (you have to follow the Parcel write and read with same order)

```
public class Note implements Parcelable {

private int id;
private String title;

public Note() {
}

Note(Parcel in){
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.title = in.readString();
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(title);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Note> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Note>(){

    @Override
    public Note createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Note(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Note[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Note[size];
    }
};
}
```

and then in your activity

Activity A

```
intent.putExtra("NOTE", note);
```

Activity B

```
Note note = (Note) getIntent().getExtras().get("NOTE");
```

**Imp:** Parcelable is 10 times faster than Serializable